# JavaScript: Class instead of ID

Tags: javascript, time, clock

I need more than one clock. In my attempt, I replaced `document.getElementById` with `Document.getElementsByClassName`. Unfortunately, it does not work the way I tried. Can someone help me please?

```js
function currentTime() {
        
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var midday = "AM";
    midday = (hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
    hour = (hour == 0) ? 12 : ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12): hour);
    hour = updateTime(hour);
    min = updateTime(min);
    
    let hours = document.createElement('span')
    let points = document.createElement('span')
    let mins = document.createElement('span')
    let blank = document.createElement('span')
    let middays = document.createElement('span')
    
    hours.innerHTML = hour
    points.innerHTML = ":"
    mins.innerHTML = min
    blank.innerHTML = " "
    middays.innerHTML = midday
    
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("clock").appendChild(hours);
    document.getElementById("clock").appendChild(points);
    document.getElementById("clock").appendChild(mins);
    document.getElementById("clock").appendChild(blank);
    document.getElementById("clock").appendChild(middays);
    
    var t = setTimeout(currentTime, 1000);
    }
    function updateTime(k) {
    if (k < 10) {
    return "0" + k;
    }
    else {
    return k;
    }
    }
    currentTime();
```

```html
<p id="clock"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const clocks = document.querySelectorAll('.clock');

function currentTime() {
        
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var midday = "AM";
  midday = (hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
  hour = (hour == 0) ? 12 : ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12): hour);
  hour = updateTime(hour);
  min = updateTime(min);
  
  const clock = `${hour}:${min} ${midday}`

  for (var i = 0; i < clocks.length; i++) {
    clocks[i].innerHTML = clock;
  }
  
  var t = setTimeout(currentTime, 1000);
  }
  function updateTime(k) {
    if (k < 10) {

         return "0" + k;
    }
    else {

         return k;
    }

  }

  currentTime();
```

```html
<p class="clock"></p>
<p class="clock"></p>
<p class="clock"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `getElementsByClassName()`, if you read the function, elements is plural. The function `getElementsByClassName()` actually returns an array! So, you just need to use:
`document.getElementsByClassName('class')[index]`.

Hopefully, you understand how arrays work. If not, here is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). I recommend reading [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) first then seeing [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I do not get it. :(

Comment: @Mantel What do you not get? `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array... You must access the right element using an index. Have you gone to either website?

Answer (score 0):

you can't have multiple id on the same page, so you need to replace that with a class and select all of them with document.querySelectorAll(".class-name") you can then loop over it.

Comment: let say you have <p class="clock"></p> <p class="clock"></p>. const clocks =   document.querySelectorAll(".clock")., so clocks becomes a nodelist you can iterate over. for (var i = 0; i < clocks.length; i++) { clocks[i].appendChild(hours)  }

Comment: Can you please use the »Copy snippet to answer« tool? Would be so thankful!

Comment: i have done that, and also did a little bit of refactoring to your code

Answer (score 0):

I done this, expect it was about your question ?

```js
function currentTime(elementsClass)
{
  let AllClock = document.getElementsByClassName(elementsClass)
    , theClock = AllClock[0]
    , hours    = document.createElement('span')
    , points   = document.createElement('span')
    , mins     = document.createElement('span')
    , blank    = document.createElement('span')
    , middays  = document.createElement('span')
    , date     = null
    , hour     = null
    , theClockInnerHTML = ''
    ;
  theClock.appendChild(hours);
  theClock.appendChild(points);
  theClock.appendChild(mins);
  theClock.appendChild(blank);
  theClock.appendChild(middays);

  points.textContent  = ":"
  blank.textContent   = " "

  updateClock()

  setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

  function updateClock()
  {
    date   = new Date()
    hour   = date.getHours()
    hours.textContent   = time2digits( (hour == 0) ? 12 : ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12): hour)  )
    mins.textContent    = time2digits( date.getMinutes())
    middays.textContent = (hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"

    if (theClock.innerHTML!=theClockInnerHTML) {
      theClockInnerHTML = theClock.innerHTML
      for(let i=1;i<AllClock.length;i++) {
        AllClock[i].innerHTML = theClockInnerHTML
      }
    }
  }
  function time2digits(k)
  {
    return (k < 10) ? ("0" + k) : k
  }
}


currentTime('clock');
```

```html
<p class="clock"></p>
<p class="clock"></p>
<p class="clock"></p>
```